# spring boot with sleuth not working traceId

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, zipkin

Hello I'm trying to use sleuth to trace a distributed system, but I'm lost because it doesn't work.

I did it as it is in the official document, but traceId and spandId are not output on console. [${applicationName}, ${traceId}, ${spanId}]

```
// build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.1")
}


group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class SimpleController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public void foo() {
        log.info(">>> hello");
    }
}
```

[image]

As you can see, traceId and spandId are not taken. I can't find the cause. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You're using an incompatible Spring Cloud version. According to [the documentation](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud), Spring Cloud 2021.0.x is only compatible with Spring Boot 2.6 and 2.7. For Spring Boot 3.0.x, you have to use Spring Cloud 2022.0.x.

However, you'll notice that Spring Cloud Sleuth does not exist in Spring Cloud 2022.0.x. This is because Spring Cloud Sleuth is end-of-life and this functionality has been moved over to [Micrometer Tracing](https://micrometer.io/docs/tracing).

So, the solution is to use the `micrometer-observation` library, which is a facade library for any observability library (kind of like slf4j is a facade for log4j, logback, ...). For distributed tracing there are two bridges (Zipkin Brave vs OpenTelemetry).

What you can do is:

1. Remove `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth` (and `spring-cloud-dependencies` if you don't use it) from your `build.gradle`
2. Add either `micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave` or `micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel` as a dependency. For example:

   ```
   implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel'
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If I remove the `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth`, I lose the **format [${applicationName}, ${traceId}, ${spanId}**]. I'm trying to use Spring 3.1.1.

- It technically works if I have the `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth` and the `micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel`, but Zipkin doesn't find it.

> `INFO [ebac-logs-sistema3, d3365d25d8999760c756c75d2f328686, 3dbbd3367c16d58d] 65466 --- [nio-8089-exec-3] d.M.ebaclogs.controller.LogsController`

- It technically works if I have the `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth` and the `micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave`, but Zipkin doesn't find it again.

> `INFO [ebac-logs-sistema3, 64c448f27a6186a48f20c16e14e57686, 8f20c16e14e57686] 65901 --- [nio-8089-exec-3] d.M.ebaclogs.controller.LogsController`

The "solution" was changing my Spring version to 2.7.1.
Still trying to make it happen on 3.1.1 though.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud Sleuth will not work with Spring Boot 3.x onward. The last major version of Spring Boot that Sleuth will support is 2.x.

[See docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/)

Comment: Reuven, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)